# ruby string interpolation and dynamic programming

Tags: ruby

So I'm trying to be smart and make a generic method which can create the variable names and use them correctly.  I am passing into 2 symbols into this method, and creating the correct variables and trying to use them.

```
 def are_numeric_fields_valid (column_name)
    single_name = column_name[0].to_s
    aggregate_name = column_name[1].to_s
    short_column_attribute = single_name.sub("_single", "")

    effective_on_attribute = :"#{short_column_attribute}_effective_on"
    expire_on_attribute = :"#{short_column_attribute}_expire_on"

      if ("loa_item.#{effective_on_attribute}".present? && "loa_item.#{expire_on_attribute}".present?) && (no_values_present?(single_name, aggregate_name))
            loa_item.errors.add(:base, "You must provide single and aggregate values when providing dates at the #{short_column_attribute} role level")
          end

end
```

But this always is true, even when the actual values are blank:

```
if ("loa_item.#{effective_on_attribute}".present? && "loa_item.#{expire_on_attribute}".present?)
```

Do I need something else so this will evaluate correctly?  Like a send?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it'll need to be different–you're calling `present?` on a string that has a value: `"loa_item.interpolated_value"` where `interpolated_value` is the string representation of `effective_on_attribute`'s evaluation.

It can't *not* be `present?` because there's an immediate, non-interpolated value.

You'd want something closer to:

```
loa_item.send(effective_on_attribute.to_sym) etc.
```

Comment: I like your *Yo!* looks.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to use `send` or a form of `eval` to "change" a string to a variable. Right now it just checks is the string is `present?`

Example: `loa_item.send(effective_on_attribute).present?`